# Is possible to create an entity with two primary key values?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm having a problem with one `Entity` which contains an `unique_key` so perhaps what I need is to create that `Entity` with two `PrimaryKey` is that even possible?

This is my `Entity`

```
@Entity
public class UserAnswerQuestion extends DateAudit {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "useranswerquestion_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "useranswerquestion_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "useranswerquestion_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    @ElementCollection
    private List<Answer> answerList;
    @ManyToOne
    private Question question;

    private Boolean passed;

    private Boolean shown;

    public UserAnswerQuestion(){
    }
....
```

And the problem when I try to create this `Entity` with another `User` it says :

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_6v3tlg1gflua8r8d4wlqxo7v5"
>     Detail: Key (answer_list_answer_id)=(11) already exists.

So what I'd like to do is make `User` as a `@Id` if possible, and maybe it solves my problem...

### EDIT

What I did is, create a class `UserAnswerQuestionId` like this :

```
public class UserAnswerQuestionId implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "useranswerquestion_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "useranswerquestion_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "useranswerquestion_seq", allocationSize = 1)
private Long id;

@Column(name ="user_id")
private Long user_id;

public UserAnswerQuestionId(){

}

public UserAnswerQuestionId(Long user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}
```

And then in the `UserAnswerQuestion` entity I changed it to :

```
 @EmbeddedId
 private UserAnswerQuestionId userAnswerQuestionId;
```

But the error now says :

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class com.pew.model.useranswers.UserAnswerQuestion
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:800) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:785) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
```

### Edit 2

I'm reading carefully the error and looks like the problem is in the

```
@ElementCollection
private List<Answer> answerList;
```

How do I solve this to allow this element repeat on this `Entity`?

Perhaps I can define those @ElementCollection not to be Unique? so can be repeated on this Entity?

This is my `Answer` Entity

```
@Entity(name = "answer")
public class Answer extends DateAudit {

@Id
@Column(name = "answer_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "answer_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "answer_seq", allocationSize = 1)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "answerToQuestion")
private String answerToQuestion;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you may need to explain your usecase better. From contextual info, looks like you want to ***retrive Users and the Answers they provided*** for various questions.In that case you may just need an association table like below.

[image: ANSWERS_FOR_QUESTIONS]

```
public class User extends DateAudit { //This assumes you are intested in retrieving User and their answer(s) in the domain model.

    @Id
    private Long id; //userid.



    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = “ANSWERS_FOR_QUESTIONS”, //More appropriate name may be : ANSWERS_BY_USERS
           joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = “user_id”) }, //fk
           inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = “question_id”) }) //fk
    private Set<Answers> answers = new HashSet<Answers>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Primary key is always only 1 and unique. It can be composite key made of multiple columns tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Including your `UserAnswerQuestionId` by using `@IdClass` should work:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(UserAnswerQuestionId.class)
public class UserAnswerQuestion extends DateAudit {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Id
    private Long user_id;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<Answer> answerList;
    @ManyToOne
    private Question question;

    private Boolean passed;

    private Boolean shown;

    public UserAnswerQuestion(){
    }
```